# How to mock/spy/stub protected methods of super class

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I have implemented a class B which is a sub class of an existing abstract class A

The abstract class (essentially):

```
public abstract class A {
   public A(Properties p, ArrayList<XXX> list) {
      ...
   }

   // There is no 0-arg constructor

   protected int doSomeWork() {
      return ...;
   }

   protected SomeObject[] findObjectsByQuery(String query) {
      return ...;
   }
}
```

My own class

```
public class B extends A {

    // this is the method I want to test
    protected int doSomeWork() {
       ...
       // calling method of super class
       // this call I want to mock/stub/whatever
       // to either return null or a mock object
       SomeObject[] myobjects = findObjectsByQuery(queryString);
       ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, the method I want to test is also protected. That's why I created an inner class Btest which inherits from B for testing purposes only:

```
private class Btest extends B {

   public Btest(Properties prop) {
      super(prop, null);
   }

   public int doSomeWork() {
      return super.doSomeWork();
   }
}
```

My test method is using Mockito with PowerMock. This is what I have so far:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class Tester {

   @Test
   public void testWrongQueryString() throws Exception {
      Properties prop = new Properties();
      Btest testObject = new Btest(prop);

      // what am I supposed to do here?
      // essentially I want to do something in the lines of
      // PowerMockito.when(/* there is a call to A.findObjectsByQuery or B.findObjectsByQuery with parameter "QueryString" */)
      //             .thenReturn(null);

      int result = testObject.doSomeWork();

      Assert.assertEquals(2, result);
   }
}
```

and this is what I tried:

```
// gives an InvocationTargetException
Btest spy = PowerMockito.spy(testObject);
PowerMockito.when(spy, "findObjectsByQuery", "QueryString").thenReturn(null);

// will not return NULL
A mock = Mockito.mock(A.class);
PowerMockito.when(mock, "findObjectsByQuery", "QueryString").thenReturn(null);
```

What am I supposed to do about it?

Comment: Protected methods are package-visible too. Move `class B` and `class Tester` into the same package and then there is no need to have the `BTest` wrapper class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I called the method to be tested with `testObject.doSomeWork()` rather than `spy.doSomeWork()`

It works like this:

```
Btest spy = PowerMockito.spy(testObject);
PowerMockito.doReturn(null).when(spy, "findObjectsByQuery", Mockito.someString());
```

with

```
int result = spy.doSomeWork();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this:

```
Btest spy = PowerMockito.spy(testObject);
PowerMockito.doReturn(null).when(spy, "findObjectsByQuery");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no InvocationTargetException now, but the call will return an empty array rather than `null` no matter what I put in `doReturn`